# Trying to get property 'prd_name' of non-object while trying to show results with for loop

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5.8

I want to retrieve some data from the DB with `for loop`, So at the Controller, I have added this:

```
$foundOrder = Cart::select('crt_content')->whereCrtId($cart->crt_id)->latest()->first();
$foundOrder = json_decode($foundOrder->crt_content);

if ($foundOrder != null) {
   foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
      $prds[] = [
          Product::with('uploaded')->wherePrdId($value->id)->select('*')->first(),
          $value->quantity,
          $value->price
      ];
   }
} else {
   $prds = [];
}
```

So `$prds` is an array and if I do `{{ dd($prds) }}`, I get this:

[image]

So at the Blade, I tried this:

```
@for($i=0;$i<=count($prds);$i++)
   {{ $prds[$i]->prd_name }}
   {{ $prds[$i]->prd_sale_price }}
@endfor
```

But it returns this error:

> Trying to get property 'prd_name' of non-object

So what is wrong here ? As you can see in the picture, I'm getting all the existing products with their attributes (such as `prd_id`, `prd_name`, `prd_sale_price`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing Product object, quantity and price in your `$prds` array. And you have array inside array. Use below code

Using `foreach` loop

```
@foreach($prds as $data)
  // in data 0 index will your product object,1 will be quantity and 2 will be price
   {{ $data[0]->prd_name }} // prd_name from product object
   {{ $data[0]->prd_sale_price }}
@endforeach
```

// using for loop

```
@for($i=0;$i<count($prds);$i++)
   {{ $prds[$i][0]->prd_name }} 
   {{ $prds[$i][0]->prd_sale_price }}
@endfor
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 4

Answer (score 0):

Your `$prds` is an array with each element have below structure:

```
[
    product,
    quantity,
    price
];
```

So if you loop through it and want to get attributes of a product, you need to get it from `$prds[$i][0]`, for example: `$prds[$i][0]->prd_name`.

**Update:** You need to loop from index `0` to `count($prds) - 1`:

```
@for($i = 0; $i <= count($prds) - 1; $i++)
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 4